# Excel 2016: How to remove single axis label or gridline from chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a line chart in Excel where the vertical axis is below 0 as some values of my graphs are negative. I have a label at -2.0%. The problem is the associated horizontal line at -2.0% intersects with the horizontal axis labels.

Is it possible to remove this line while letting all others remain? Or can I remove a single axis label (including its line)?

My workaround right now is to change the scale because the only other alternative I see is to have the labels above the chart, which is not what I want.

Comment: an image of the chart may help others understand your problem

Comment: "Is it possible to remove this line while letting all others remain? Or can I remove a single axis label (including its line)?" - no, that's not possible in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Here is a kludge:

1. Select the cell with the label in question
2. Type in one or more carriage returns (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>) *before* the text

You'll need to experiment to see how many carriage returns will be needed